# Always execute Code and the end of a python script

Tags: python, jenkins

Is there a way in Python to have a block of code always execute at the end of a program (barring a `kill -9`?

We have a Jenkins project that launches a python script as part of the build process. If a developer decides to abort the job, then there are a lot of artifacts left lying around that can (and are) influencing future builds.

Is there anyway to ensure that the cleanup portion of the python script is run?

Comment: Have a separate `cleanup.py` script, and run the both from a `bash` script?

Comment: I looked into that, but Jenkis cancels everything that was spawned by the build. May need to make a separate "cleanup" job.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Why isn't wrapping the whole program in `try` with cleanup actions in `finally` acceptable?

Comment: Because this is to prevent anything from disrupting the cleanup. If I wanted to try/catch I would be messing with the default error handling, no? I know in Ruby it is a terrible idea to catch "Exception", which is what I think I would need to do to catch everything. Also, this program is not terminated by itself. A parent program (jenkins) terminates it.

Comment: `finally` neither catches nor suppresses exceptions.  It runs without fail no matter how the try-block was executed.  I made two short example programs to test this.  In one I called `sys.exit()` in the try block and the finally clause printed to std out to show that it was run.  In the second program I put `time.sleep(20)` in the try block and then interrupted the script with ctrl-c.  Again, the finally clause printed its message.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mean to use the exception handling portion, just the `finally` portion, gotcha. I guess that would work as well. However, we've already implemented the other solution and it is working for us. Unless that is committing some Python taboo, I'd rather not go back and mess with it more. That would just get me on my SCRUM Master's bad side :-) Thanks for the suggestion and I'll remember it in the future!

Comment: @DevonFinninger:  I had initially assumed you knew about `finally` but that it did not fit your needs and was trying to figure out why.  I think the `atexit` solution is nifty and the right way to go.  I especially like the decorator version.  It makes sense to define clean-up in the same place that you define acquisition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `atexit` exit handlers. Here's an example from the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html):

```
try:
    _count = int(open("counter").read())
except IOError:
    _count = 0

def incrcounter(n):
    global _count
    _count = _count + n

def savecounter():
    open("counter", "w").write("%d" % _count)

import atexit
atexit.register(savecounter)
```

Comment: Never knew about `atexit`. Should be pretty useful.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll report back later if it works.

Comment: Looks like this will work out great for us. Thanks! Answer accepted.