# What is the most Pythonic way to ensure that a line of code always executes, even when a return/break executes above the code?

Tags: python

For example, in the following code, the line `print("Finished computation")` will not be executed:

```
def test():
    print("Starting computation...")
    if True:
        return 0
    print("Finished computation")
```

One way to guarantee that code executes is with a `try`/`finally`:

```
def test():
    try:
        print("Starting computation...")
        if True:
            return 0
    finally:
        print("Finished computation")
```

It feels a bit odd because a `try` is used without a `catch`. Is this considered the most Pythonic way to guarantee execution?

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887826/always-execute-code-and-the-end-of-a-python-script/

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do.  Your question reads as "I wrote my program specifically so it does `A`; how can I make it do `B` instead?"  The obvious answer is don't write it to do `A` in the first place.

Comment: The [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html) specifically states that ".. that `finally` clause is executed before really leaving the function", so I guess it must be the most Pythonic by design.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution to using `finally` - a shutdown function that executes when the program closes, relying on the `atexit` module (an exit handler).  The shutdown function only executes when the code terminates normally - it won't execute if a kill signal is sent. Perhaps others could comment on whether this is really the pythonic solution.

```
def shutdown():
  print("Finished computation")

def test():
  print("Starting computation...")
  if True:
    return 0

import atexit
atexit.register(shutdown)
test()
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this just adding the `except` looks fine for me.

```
def test():
    try:
        print("Starting computation...")
        0/0
        if True:
            return 0
    except:
        print("error")
    finally:
        print("Finished computation")
```

Answer (score -2):

You could set a return value to a variable and then return the variable indefinitely at the end of the function.

```
def test():
    #return variable
    ret = None
    print("Starting computation...")
    if True:
        #set return variable
        ret = 0
    print("Finished computation") 

    return ret
```

Comment: Yep, this is the 'Standard Way' but in really big codes this is not really readable

Comment: IMO the computation has't finished until the value has been returned